# schema.ini file to export from Access

Tags: ms-access, export, ini

I'm exporting from an Access DB via VBscript and want to try using a Schema.ini file. I have a batch program that fires off a vbscript file that opens the Access DB and does the export. My vbscript filename is export.vbs.

If I have:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "", "table", "C:\output\table.csv"
```

I notice while the export is happening a file gets automatically created "export.ini".

If I have

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "Schema.ini", "table", "C:\output\table.csv"
```

I get an error talking about "The text file spec 'Schema.ini" does not exist." even though in the same directory this is all happening in I have a Schema.ini file there. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go about it a different way ( [Create comma separated file (csv) from access - scheduled daily from windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482242/create-comma-separated-file-csv-from-access-scheduled-daily-from-windows/13483597#13483597) )

```
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=z:\Docs\test.accdb"

sSQL = "select * into " 
sSQL= sSQL & "[text;database=z:\docs\;FMT=Delimited;HDR=Yes].[csvfile.csv]"
sSQL= sSQL & " from table1"

cn.Execute sSQL
```

Comment: I'd like to note that this method is *much faster* than `DoCmd.TransferText`.  I have a loop that will export all tables to .csv files.  Using `DoCmd.TransferText` it took 55 seconds, using this `SELECT * INTO` method took 16 seconds.
I also want to note that this method will leave a `schema.ini` in the output folder appended with data about all tables exported.  DoCmd.TransferText will leave a `export.ini` file in the folder if the last processed table was empty (tested in Access 2016).

Comment: Here is the table export loop code that I started with:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44557992/1898524